# I'm trying to create a foreign key but MYSQL is creating just a "key"

Tags: mysql

So I create these tables...

```
create table authors(
name varchar(55) primary key
)

create table books(
name varchar(55),
author varchar(55),
foreign key(author) references authors(name)
)
```

(my foreign key syntax was taken from here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Then I run this mysql...
    show create table books;

The result is:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
 `name` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
 `author` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `author` (`author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

It just says `KEY` it doesn't say foreign key.

Then I go to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` and `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` and `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME` values are both null for `books`.`author`.

I'm trying to query my database to show all foreign keys in a table...but it seems I'm having trouble creating foreign keys in the first place. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENGINE=MyISAM` don't support `FK`, use innoDB

just run below command to change your table engine to `innoDB`

```
ALTER TABLE books ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

After that you can create FK

Comment: Thanks...had to alter both tables actually. I don't even know what an engine is but okay it works.

Comment: Ya, Foreign  Keys work from InnoDB to InnoDB table, you can add Constrains to perform action on `UPDATE` or `DELETE`

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys are not supported by the `MyISAM` engine, only in `InnoDB`.